# AWS CDK How to set up correct Content-Type for GateWay

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to create an integration between an API Gateway and my queue. The goal of which is to create a gateway that will be a webhook for our SendGrid to send events relating to emails being sent, bounced, etc; the gateway will simply pass the data to a queue directly. After much trial and error I was finally able to get it to get to the deployment stage only for it to fail with the following cryptic error: `[Invalid mapping expression specified: application/x-www-form-urlencoded]`.

Looking at other places on SO, seems to reference that it uses VTL language, and as such the Content-Type should be surrounded by single brackets as well. As such, I've switched my dictionary to reflect that:

```
            {
                { "integration.request.header.Content-Type", "'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'" }
            };
```

However, upon executing the pipeline anew, it does not actually pass the Preparation stage, and instead just says the following `Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError`. Because no stack was made, I cannot see what events occurred exactly. My integration request looks like so, where am I going wrong? I used (https://sbstjn.com/blog/aws-cdk-api-gateway-service-integration-sqs/) and (https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-integrate-api-gateway-and-sqs-with-aws-cdk-14e74e7de5ba) as resources, and I noticed they have the specific content-type in single quotes. CDK portion of code in question:

```
var integrationRole = new Role(this, "SendGrid-Webhook-Integration-Role", new RoleProps()
            {
                AssumedBy = new ServicePrincipal("apigateway.amazonaws.com")
            });

            sqsFunc.Queue1.GrantSendMessages(integrationRole);

            var restApi = new RestApi(this, "SendGrid-Webhook-API");
            
            var requestParams = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "integration.request.header.Content-Type", "'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'" }
            };

            var requestTemplate = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "application/json",  "Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=$input.body"}
            };

            var integration = new AwsIntegration(new AwsIntegrationProps
            {
                Service = "sqs",
                IntegrationHttpMethod = "POST",
                Path = $"{props.Env.Account}/Communications-SendGridWebhook",
                Options = new IntegrationOptions
                {
                    CredentialsRole = integrationRole,
                    PassthroughBehavior = PassthroughBehavior.NEVER,
                    RequestParameters = requestParams,
                    RequestTemplates = requestTemplate,
                    IntegrationResponses = new List<IntegrationResponse>() {
                        new IntegrationResponse { StatusCode = "200"}
                    }.ToArray()
                }
            });


            restApi.Root.AddMethod("POST", integration);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was rather simple, because when I first ran the pipeline with my content-type not having the '' around what it expects, the stack failed to build. It was stuck in a rollback complete state which meant I manually had to delete it.

Deleting it, and adding the '' quotes solved the issue